# Increasing the space between secondary y axis and its title

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, yaxis

I have plotted a graph with two y-axes. However, the titles of the axes are a little too close to them for my taste. I've managed to distance the primary axis title but can't figure out how to do the same for the secondary axis. Here is the code I've used:

```
ggplot(data1, aes(x=year))+
geom_line(aes(y= data1$`export share`, colour= "export share"), size = 2)+
  geom_line(aes(y=data1$pm25/coeff, colour= "pm25"), size = 2)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 17), name = "Year")+
  scale_y_continuous(name="Export Share of GDP", labels = scales::percent, sec.axis=sec_axis(trans = ~.*coeff, name = "PM2.5"))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0)), axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = 5) ,legend.title = element_blank(), legend.box.margin = margin(0,0,0,10), text = element_text(size = 30)) +
  scale_colour_discrete("",
                        breaks=c("export share", "pm25"),
                        labels=c("Export Share of GDP", "PM2.5")) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=2006) +
   geom_vline(xintercept = 2000)
```

[image: And here's a picture of the graph]

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it didn't seem to change anything except create a margin to the left of the primary axis.

Comment: The best victories are the battles that we never fought. I would recommend avoiding the secondary y-axis entirely. Two graphics one below the other would be  more appropriate. A secondary y-axis might yield visual confusion. I would suggest this [reading](https://blog.datawrapper.de/dualaxis/) to make my case.

Comment: I would avoid using dual y axes. In most cases it is not a good idea. I would pivot your data long, index the measurements to some starting number (the value at year 2000), and then plot them on the same axis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can increase the margin on the right by increasing the second argument of `plot.margin`

```
+ theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,3,1,1), "cm"))
```

And then increase the `vjust` argument of `axis.title.y.right`:

```
+ theme(axis.title.y.right = element_text(vjust=2 or 3 or 4))
```

Larger numbers for `vjust` go further away from the axis. Of course you combine the above two "theme" commands into one.